# Overriding equals() and hashCode() methods of HashMap implementation

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a hashmap of the type `HashMap<Long, ArrayList<String>>`.

I need to override the equals() and hashCode() methods to gain in performance. What should be the overriding function like, for this case ?

I knew the exact no. of elements I would be putting in the HashMap, thus I have used `initial Capacity = (No. Of Elements that will be put)/ 0.75`

where 0.75=> load factor, 
Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you believe that the equals() and hashCode() methods on HashMap are a performance bottleneck? These classes have been well-tested and used all over the place.

Comment: There are very specific contracts for the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of all `Map` and `Collection` implementations. As the others have said, you aren't really going to get any better than the existing implementations within the contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `equals(..)` method of `HashMap` has linear complexity. So does the one of `ArrayList`. I don't think it can get any better - you have to compare each element

Answer (score 1):

You may assume the Java library objects like `Long`, `ArrayList` and `String` have correct implementations for `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

(You are correct in that when you use an object as key in a `HashMap` you should make sure it has consistent implementations for those methods)